# AttributeError- SQLAlchemy Flask

Tags: sql, python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Estou tentando criar uma query usando Flask-SQLAlchemy

A Flask deve me retornar uma lista de livros de acordo com a pesquisa do usuário.
Ele seleciona 4 opções de busca e digita um input para pesquisar.

EX:
Ele seleciona busca por TITULO e digita "Lord" como input.

A query deve retornar todos os livros que contém a palavra Lord no TITULO.

Eu tenho 2 variáveis

```
info_type = request.form.get('book_tags')
book_info = request.form.get('search_value').lower()
```

E a query

```
Book.query.filter(Book.info_type.contains(book_info).all()
```

Se eu substituir a variável "info_type" diretamente por ISBN, TITLE, AUTHOR, YEAR (possíveis valores para a variável info_type) funciona nomralmemnte.

ex:

```
Book.query.filter(Book.author.contains(book_info).all()
```

Porém eu preciso de uma variável, pois há 4 diferentes tipos de pesquisa.

Alguem pode me dar alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Tente com `like` para ver se funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui entender o seu problema - 
você precisa praticar um pouco com a linguagem, e entender a diferença de strings, vairáveis e atributos  -

Não é por que o nome do atributo que você precisa está dentro da variável `info_type`, que esse nome vai automaticamente virar o atributo quando você usar `Book.info_type`.

Há linguagens de programação inclusive em que isso é impossível - só com uma sequência de `if`s mesmo - ,

Em Python há sim, como usar a string que está dentro da variável info_type para recupear o atributo de mesmo nome no objeto `Book` - tem que se usar a função `getattr`.

Em resumo, o que você precisa especificamente pra passar essa etapa é:

```
Book.query.filter(getattr(Book, info_type).contains(book_info).all()
```

Mas eu recomendaria realmente bastante, mas bastante prática no modo interativo da linguagem para entender a diferença entre digitar um nome de atributo diretamente no código, e ter esse nome dentro de uma variável, dentre outras coisas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Já estava há uns 5 dias tentando resolver isso.

Estou aprendendo agora esse framework, vou me aprofundar mais!

Obrigado novamente!